# Fade/Redraw/Modify ImageIcon on click in SWING JLabel on the fly

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel

I want a JLabel with an Icon to look "clicked", when mouse is clicked on the Label. The Label contains an ImageIcon. Instead of changing the icon to another one, I want to redraw the ImageIcon with another colorset (e.g.: setXORMode(new Color(255,0,0) ) "on the fly". Anyone has a hint how to manage that?

```
JLabel my_label = new JLabel("");
my_label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("/path/to/resources/myicon.jpg")));
my_label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //HERE I NEED THE VODOO :)
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the image one that you read in from disk or the network as opposed to one that you create on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you read the image into from disk you would do something like this.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("images/BB.jpg");
BufferedImage picture = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Later when you need to change XOrMode you would do the following:

```
Graphics2D g = picture.createGraphics();
g.setXORMode(new Color(255,0,0) )
g.dispose();
```

If you want to fadein/fadeout, I'd recommend the [timing framework](http://timingframework.dev.java.net/).  Also, if you want to repaint the part of the label itself in addition to the image in the label, you can override `void paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

A very good resource for that you might consider looking into is the book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/).  It's full of this kind of stuff.  If you look the examples on the website from Chapter 4 there is some sample image code that might be useful.  It would be a very, very good book for you to pick up too.

Comment: Thanks - that is what I was thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`LookupOp`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/LookupOp.html) to modify a copy of the icon when it's loaded. Then use `setIcon()` in the mouse handler.

Comment: I like both solutions, but I prefer the other one. Thanks for your answer; +1 Vote from me for you.